# htaccess 301 redirect rule for forum profile links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I switched forum platforms and I'd like to redirect requests to member profiles using a 301 redirect.

The old platform path to user profiles was: www.example.com/forum/member.php?u=XXXXXX
The new platform path to user profiles is:  www.example.com/user/XXXXXX

The user IDs have remained the same during the switch.

I tried to accomplish this by writing the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/member.php?u=(.*)$ http://www.example.com/user/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, it's not working for some reason and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
-Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the query string from a RewriteRule directive.

Try the following instead.

```
#if the query string has a u parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)u=([^&]+) [NC}
RewriteRule ^forum/member.php$ http://www.example.com/user/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So that gets the job done, thanks! However, it leaves me with this string at the end: '/user/1?u=1' when it should only be '/user/1'. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: NM. Adding ? mark to the end '...%2?' removes the left over query. Sweet!